# Generating Oracle Apex Master-Detail Forms by code

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a huge number of tables which I want to present by Oracle APEX. Instead of adding them in the UI, can I generate those Forms with sql?

Comment: Technically yes, but it is not simple. Export an Apex page and open the export file to get an idea of how you can create Apex pages and forms using the API in PL/SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a novel suggestion.  It should work.

1. Start the Create Application wizard
2. Add a Form and Report for any table in the wizard.
3. Still in the Create Application Wizard, click "View Blueprint".
4. Examine that JSON document and look for the section called "pages".  You should see a JSON object that looks like the attached image. It's these page objects that you need to generate.  You could programmatically create a JSON document
   representing your additional pages.
5. Paste in this window the updated blueprint and click Apply Blueprint. Your Create Application wizard should now be updated for all of your additional pages.

[image]

Comment: Oh, that's neat! I hadn't noticed that feature yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use QuickSQL utility under SQL Workshop. it will create the tables and create an applications using those tables.Even if there are existing tables, you can include drop tables statements in your script.